# curl with NSS and centos does not work

Tags: centos, curl, ssl, nss

I am using below command to connect:-

```
curl --cert-type P12 --cert ./my.p12:password --cacert ./my-cert.pem https://host:8443/api/root
```

but getting this ERROR:

> curl: (58) unable to load client cert: -8018
> (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)

curl version ==:

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.53.1 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

OS version :-

> CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

curl with -v results :

> - About to connect() to host port 8443 (#0)
> - Trying 10.X.X.X
> - Connected to host (10.X.X.X) port 8443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: ./my-cert.pem   CApath: none
> - unable to load client cert: -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)
> - NSS error -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)
> - Unknown PKCS #11 error.
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (58) unable to load client cert: -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)

Comment: Can you share the specific URL?

Comment: it is a restricted web server..

Comment: Have you taken a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265100/curl-command-unable-to-load-client-cert-8018

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> taken [from here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1653648)

Change the following line in the configuration file ***/etc/opensc/opensc.conf***:

```
# reader_drivers = openct, pcsc, ctapi;
```

to:

```
reader_drivers = pcsc;
```

Comment: I dont have this file.

Comment: not sure how will this work...mine is centos7

Comment: A google of the key words ***opensec.conf location centos*** directed me to this page https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/opensc-0.19.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html, which showed the location on CentOS to be at ***/etc/opensec.conf***. C'mon now, a little effort on your part is required

Comment: yeah Buddy..I checked the same location..

Comment: It seemed I need to have smart card confgured by admin

Comment: seems a related question https://superuser.com/questions/1367608/smart-card-issue-with-opensc-pklogin-finder-debug-only-on-centos.

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have the necessary libraries installed. Perhaps having a look at this solution will provide the answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265100/curl-command-unable-to-load-client-cert-8018

Comment: sure..thank you